# React Testing Library - mocking a function

Tags: reactjs, function, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

I am trying to test a function gets called

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import MyForm from './MyForm';

afterEach(cleanup);
const testFunction = jest.fn();
test('my form', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<MyForm />);
  const myButton = getByTestId('submit-button');
  expect(myButton.tagName).toBe('BUTTON');
  fireEvent.click(myButton)
  expect(testFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
});
```

The problem I am having is it does not seem to bind to the mock function but it does call the function in the component.

```
import React from 'react';

export default function myForm() {
  function testFunction() {
    console.log('hello from inside');
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={testFunction}>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit" data-testid="submit-button">submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

How do I get the mock function the be called rather than the 'real' function.

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    
    Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.
```

Comment: Does your `testFunction` have to be (hidden) inside the myForm component? If it were a prop, you could pass it in your test and then the mock function would get called.

Comment: I have seen that done - in almost every example. I would be modifying my code to fit the test. I could but it  seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call the internal functions of `myForm`. You can test the behavior and the final tangible output but not private functionality of a component.

And it does make sense as well. A unit test should concern itself with the outcome and not if a specific function internal to that component is called.

Yes, you can always test the *behavior*. For instance, you can test that `console.log` is called cos that is visible to the outside world in terms of a tangible thing.

Similarly, if `testFuntion` does something else which you can assert, you can test that as well.

Another option is to pull `testFunction` out and export it so it can be used anywhere. Then you write a unit test for just `testFunction`'s functionality may be, but not within the context of the components unit test